# php: how to identify the "includes" of a page

Tags: php, include

I am in pageA.php with the following code

```
if (DOWNLOAD_ENABLED == 'true') include 'pageB.php';
```

is it possible to know inside pageB.php that pageA.php included it? I need to perform certain actions in pageB.php according to the page that includes it.

Comment: require and require_once. If the file is not loaded it will fail

Comment: My question is how to know inside pageB.php that it was called by pageA.php, is there a function for this?

Comment: you can also check `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];`

Comment: thanks Akam, this server variable also works nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any variable declared in pageA will be accessible in pageB, this is not very nice practice, you should be using Object oriented or at the very least functions for this, but if you absolutely have to you can do something like:

```
// on pageA.php
if (DOWNLOAD_ENABLED == 'true') {
  $includedFrom = "pageA";
  include 'pageB.php';
}

// on pageB.php
switch($includedFrom) {
  case "pageA":
    // do stuff
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to save it in a var.

```
$my_page = 'pageA.php';

if (DOWNLOAD_ENABLED == 'true') include 'pageB.php';
```

You can access `$my_page` in `pageB.php` normally.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work:

**pageA.php**

```
define('AUTHORISED_TO_INCLUDE', 1);
if (DOWNLOAD_ENABLED == 'true') include 'pageB.php';
```

**pageB.php**

```
if(!defined('AUTHORISED_TO_INCLUDE')) // Do something, e.g. die();
```